# Bash script - string with spaces in argument used for call tshark in script

Tags: bash, parameter-passing, whitespace

decode_bip_MCShark.sh:

```
cd $1
echo tshark -r $2 -Y $3 $4 -T fields
tshark -r $2 -Y $3 $4 -T fields
```

---

run command

```
sh decode_bip_MCShark.sh /home/ute/ A.pcap '"3gpp.subcellid == 0 && Length != 0x00000000"' '-e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.prachPreambleIndex -e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.initialTa'
```

result：

```
tshark -r A.pcap -Y "3gpp.subcellid == 0 && Length != 0x00000000" -e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.prachPreambleIndex -e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.initialTa -T fields

tshark: Display filters were specified both with "-Y" and with additional command-line arguments.
```

---

directly run command:

```
tshark -r A.pcap -Y "3gpp.subcellid == 0 && Length != 0x00000000" -e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.prachPreambleIndex -e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.initialTa -T fields
```

without error in result

---

I had a windows bat file which can work under windows system:

```
cd %1
tshark -r %2 -Y %3 %~4  -T fields
```

in this windows bat，%~4 replace the %4.

Now in Linux shell bash，how to get same function？

Answer (score 1):

```bash
cd "$1"
echo tshark -r "$2" -Y "$3" $4 -T fields
tshark -r "$2" -Y "$3" $4 -T fields
```

Bash is not a usual language. At first glance it looks a little bit like any other language, with loops, functions, variables, etc. But there are some major differences. And struggling with escapes, quotes, etc, is one symptom of being not aware of those differences. There is no other cure to that than taking the time to read and understand how it works. Many thing in computer can be learned by examples, imitations, and then generalisation. But that won't cut for bash. I know lot of people able to write 1000 lines of bash, but who would struggle with those quotes tuning randomly where to put them and where to remove them, adding randomly , for hours before it accidentally starts working.

In particular, in this case, one important point to understand is variable substitutions. In bash, variables (but also patterns, results of subshells, etc. And with a given order that it is important to know) are substituted in the command line before the command execution.

So when you call

```bash
myscript foo bar "hello world"
```

Inside `myscript`, $1 is `foo`, $2 is `bar` and $3 is `hello world`.
So, if myscript in turn calls

```bash
printf "<%s>\n" $1 $2 $3
```

(printing one line for each of printf arguments)
$x are first substituted by their values, so that what is really executed is

```bash
printf "<%s>\n" foo bar hello world
```

Then, command line arguments are splitted and quotes are removed

And then that command is split (word splitting) into

```
command printf, with arguments
"<%s>\n"
foo
bar
hello
world
```

Quotes from command line are removed, so

```
printf
<%s>\n
foo
bar
hello
wolrd
```

Which is executed, leading to the result

```
<foo>
<bar>
<hello>
<world>
```

If you try to solve that by adding an extra layer of quotes in your initial argument, it is more complicated.

```bash
./myscript foo bar '"hello world"'
```

will result, in myscript, in $1 being `foo`, $2 being `bar` and $3 being `"hello world"`
So, variable substitution occurs my printf becomes

```bash
printf "<%s>\n" foo bar "hello world"
```

Then, word splitting occurs. And that is tricky: splitting takes into account all spaces that are there after the previous substitutions, but did not appeared between quotes.
But those quotes had to be there before the substitutions (otherwise the spaces did not appeared between quotes).

(in other words, spaces that appear because of substitution influence word splitting, but quotes that appear because of substitutions do not)

So, command is split into

```
printf
"<%s>\n"
foo
bar
"hello
world"
```

After quotes removal (the one from the command line, so not those in `"hello` and `world"`)

```
printf
<%s>\n
foo
bar
"hello
world"
```

Hence the result

```
<foo>
<bar>
<"hello>
<world">
```

So, what you have to do is

```bash
./myscript foo bar "hello world"
```

But then, into myscript, to ensure that what is in $3 is not split into separate words if some spaces appear,

```bash
printf "<%s>\n" "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

That way, `$1` is `foo`, `$2` is `bar`, `$3` is `hello world`.
After variable substitution you get

```bash
printf "<%s>\n" "foo" "bar" "hello world"
```

After word splitting (not taking into account spaces that appeared between quotes)

```
printf
"<%s>\n"
"foo"
"bar"
"hello world"
```

After quote removal

```
printf
<%s>\n
foo
bar
hello world
```

with result

```
<foo>
<bar>
<hello world>
```

as expected.

So, simple. But only if you keep in mind the successive substitutions that occur.

If you need to have a variable number of extra arguments to pass to tshark, the sanest way, I think, would be to have a variable number of extra arguments passed to your script.

```bash
cd "$1"
rArg="$2"
YArg="$3"
shift 3

echo tshark -r "${rArg}" -Y "${YArg}" "$@" -T fields
tshark -r "${rArg}" -Y "${YArg}" "$@" -T fields
```

Then call your script with

```bash
bash decode_bip_MCShark.sh /home/ute/ A.pcap '3gpp.subcellid == 0 && Length != 0x00000000' -e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.prachPreambleIndex -e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.initialTa
```

Then, you could even quote some of the extra arguments if needed, while still have them as separate arguments.

Bottom line is: it is very rarely a good idea to have literal quotes (I mean, unless they are part of a text, like in "don't" or "can't"), that is quotes inside quotes, or escaped quotes.
I don't they it never is. But overwhelmingly, when you are doing that, it means that you are doing something wrong, that it would fail in some situations, and there is a better solution.

Comment: Plus, don't pass the argument with **both** single and double quotes: one or the other only.

Comment: Yep. I was wondering if those were another attempt to solve the problem, of it those quotes are intended for tshark

Comment: `tshark -r A.pcap -Y "3gpp.subcellid == 0 && Length != 0x00000000" -e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.prachPreambleIndex -e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.initialTa -T fields`
is a working command.
`tshark -r A.pcap -Y 3gpp.subcellid == 0 && Length != 0x00000000 -e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.prachPreambleIndex -e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.initialTa -T fields`, this one can not work.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Your solution's result is like this:
`tshark -r /home/ute/22R4_CNI81085_UL-Connection_FDD_CPRI_ABIL_AREA_FR1_PRACH-5M-SNR-5_UL_bip_log.pcap -Y "3gpp.subcellid == 0 && Length != 0x00000000" -e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.prachPreambleIndex -e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.initialTa -T fields
--------------------------------------------------------
tshark: Some fields aren't valid:
         UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.prachPreambleIndex -e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.initialTa`

Comment: echo output is same like before (my output), but tshark response now it can recognize first -e parameter, but still think second -e parameter as part of first -e parameter, it think only one -e parameter.

Comment: You should edit your question with an example of the inputs. That error message looks like you have `$4` set to `-e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.prachPreambleIndex -e UlData_detectedPrachPreambles_t.initialTa`. The quick bandaid solution is to leave `$4` unquoted, but really you should read [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and [Quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) and try to build your inputs following some of their examples.

Comment: @gsmgxm I've added a suggestion about that at the end.